# Why not call Destructor in C++?

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

I studding `C++` concept. I'm confused in constructor and Destractor concept. Destructor will be invoked implicitly by the compiler upon exit from the program. But in my program, only constructor called.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
        int i;
public:
        A()
        {
                cout<<"Constructor call"<<endl;
        }
        ~A()
        {
                cout<<"Destructtor call"<<endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
        A *a = new A();
}
```

**Output:**

```
Constructor call
```

So, I have question : **Why destructor not call implicit by the compiler upon exit program?**

Comment: "Destructor will be invoked implicitly by the compiler upon exit from the program" is wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why destructor not call implicit by the compiler upon exit program?

Because dynamically allocated objects are not destroyed automatically. That is how the language has been specified. Tracking the destruction of dynamic objects would require runtime / memory overhead.

Solution: Do not leak dynamically allocated objects.

Comment: And use smart pointers to manage heap memory. RAII, and destructors in general, are one of the killer features of C++.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 "types" of variable lifetime in C++. Dynamic and automatic.

Automatic is something like :

```
void foo()
{
  int i; // automatic storage
} // destroys i
```

Here, `i` will be destructed the moment it leaves scope (after `foo` returns). You can check this for yourself by making your object have an automatic lifetime:

```
int main()
{
    A a; // calls A's constructor and allocates memory.
} //calls A's destructor and frees the memory used.
```

You'll see that both the constructor and the destructor will get called.

---

The second form is dynamically allocated memory. You can dynamically allocate memory by using `new` (like you did) and free that memory by using `delete`. The compiler *won't* do this for you.
This means that, to destruct your object you have to call `delete` explicitly yourself:

```
int main()
{
        A* a = new A();
        delete a; // calls A's destructor and frees the memory used.
}
```

If you do not call `delete` (like your code) then the moment the program leaves `main` the pointer `a` is destroyed and now we have a piece of memory that nothing can reach and thus nobody can clean up (with `delete`) which means you're [*leaking* memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

However, modern operating systems reclaim all memory used by the program automatically the moment the program ends so at this point it won't matter too much. This does mean your destructor won't be called as you've just witnessed.

---

Dynamically allocated memory allows you to do some nifty tricks like controlling the lifetime of your objects to the point where you want to destroy them explicitly yourself with `delete`. The problem with using `new` and `delete` is that it's so easy to forget a single `delete` and your program will already leak memory, which is why it's advised to stay away from this way of allocation.

If for some reason you absolutely need dynamic lifetime then use a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` that will call `new` and `delete` for you the moment it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

You create the object dynamically with `new`. The destructor will only be called when the objected is deleted with `delete`.

To prevent memory leaks, you could/should use smart pointers like `unique_ptr`.

In any case, the memory itself will of course be released when the process ends.

Answer (score 2):

The destructor is never called in your code because the object is never destroyed.

You dynamically allocate the `A` object and you never deallocate it. Add `delete a;` into `main()` and you'll see the destructor in action:

```
int main()
{
    A *a = new A();
    delete a;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your main function, you create a pointer variable that you must delete it by `delete a` at end of main function.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a memory leak. You *dynamically* created an object with `new`, promising that you would manage the lifetime of the object and clean it up later with `delete`. Then you broke that promise.

If you create an object in the usual fashion:

```
A a;
```

then it will be destroyed automatically for you.